# ASP.NET MVC How to organize an often changing front page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have build an website for my firm using standard ASP.NET MVC tools. Most of the content is quite static and doesn't need database backing. 
Unfortunately, the marketing team loves to tweak the text on the front page - at the moment every change has to go through me. I would like to implement so kind of cms. At first I thought about rolling my own - but that problem should be already solved.

But I did not find the right tool for the job - can anybody point me at a good nuget package etc?

Some background:
front page has ~4 seperate blocks of text (default project is a good approximation), which should be changed at will. Major layout changes need not the be done in the software.

Comment: This will most likely be closed since you are asking for a tool.  But, since you are only changing 4 blocks of text, convert those to `@Html.Action` blocks with partial views, give your users a simple backend to change text and persist to a SQL Express (or local db) to render out.

Comment: @Tommy That was my first idea - but I would have liked something which doen't require so much handwiring ;)